# Joomla adds /joomla30 to my website

Tags: joomla-3.x, url

I have Joomla 3 installed on my host and am building my site. When I try to go to my site, I get 404 not found. Joomla has added /joomla30 to my site and must be added in order to access my website. How can I change this?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your issue?  what is joomla30? is it folder? do you have SEF enabled in your site?

Comment: Have you edited your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to the name of the folder. If you have joomla inside, for example: root/joomla30/ and you didn't configure anything yet, then you will surely be able to get to joomla only by typing http://mywebsite.com/joomla30.

After a complete installation, you will be able to redirect joomla30 to anythingyouwant using your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to your `.htaccess` file. Check if this file has something like

```
RewriteBase /joomla30
```

inside. Also make sure Joomla is installed in the root directory of your domain, and not in a subdirectory.